# "Could not load type" error trying to install HTTPModule on IIS6 - Web.config error

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, httpmodule

Two hours of searching Google and Stackoverflow and I've gotten nowhere.  This is not related to code-behind, which is why I've had no luck so far.

Here's my problem: I have a legacy website running IIS6 and I need to install an HTTPModule on it to add some processing to any request for a specific file type.  I've written the module, copied it over to the application's /bin directory, and added the following to my Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="YourModule" type="SecurityModule.SecurityModule" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Then I fire up the website and... "Server Error in /MyApplication".

Here is the entirety of what it gives me:

---

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'SecurityModule.SecurityModule'. (D:\Websites\Reports\web.config line 4)

Source Error:

```
Line 2:     <system.web>
Line 3:       <httpModules>
-->Line 4:            <add name="YourModule" type="SecurityModule.SecurityModule" />
Line 5:       </httpModules>
Line 6:     </system.web>
```

Source File: D:\Websites\Reports\web.config    Line: 4

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3625; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618

---

Line 4, where I added an arrow, is red.  And that's it!  No explanation, no hints on where to go.  Just "Could not load type".  I have tried all sorts of things to get around this:

- Played with the name of the module in case I got it wrong.  And the string in the type.
- Changed /Bin to /bin
- Make sure the module was compiled against the .NET Framework 2.0
- Abandoned web.config and tried setting it up as a mapping in IIS 6 (got 404s from that one).
- Related to previous, tried making all files of my extension go through the ASP.NET ISAPI module with a wildcard mapping and configuring the module.  Brought me full circle back to this error.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?  Or, failing that, can someone point me in a direction?  At this point, any direction will do. :)  I'm at a complete dead end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use an assembly qualified name.

```
NamespaceQualifiedTypeName, AssemblyName
```

Comment: Fair enough, but the examples and forum posts I've seen don't appear to require it.  Is this actually required?

Comment: @AriRoth You might have got your answer by now, but for those looking up this one later, yes you need to provide fully qualified name. Also this is a MS answer on assembly loading in general: http://forums.asp.net/t/1945391.aspx?+Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+error+when+referencing+HttpModule+using+partial+name+

Comment: This helped me, I was missing the class name from the  NameSpaceQualifiedName.

Comment: ex: `<add name="MyModule" type="MySolution.Web.MyHttpModule, MySolution.Web" />`